# Is it possible to index using a variable of the for/loop in vhdl?

Tags: loops, for-loop, matrix, indexing, vhdl

I'm a novice of VHDL code.

I would like to index a shared variable using the variable defined in the for/loop. It seems to work in simulation although the compiler tells me there are some warning:

(ID: 13024). Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on board as expected from the warning.

I want to use for/loop because they seem good to reduce the complexity of the "total combinational functions" used, so I want to index in a stupid way, my shared variable.

This is an extract of my code:

```
for I in I_top to I_top loop
for J in J_top to J_top loop

    if type = 1 then
        matrix(I,J) := "110";   
        vector(I) := vector(I) + 1;
        end := true;
    elsif type = 2 then
    ...
    end if;
end loop;
end loop;
```

Comment: Are these for loops inside a process? `for ... loop` won't work outside a process, though `for ... generate` would work instead.

Comment: In the current language, shared variables are only allowed with protected types.  You can use a regular variable that is defined in the process.

Comment: This for ... loop are used inside a process. They work in simulation, but not on board. Now I have replaced the shared variables with signals but it always works only in simulation.

Comment: I think this snippet is not synthesizable. Have you ever imagine what kind of combination logic which allow increasing without clock or can break it anytime. It look like computer program than hardware design.

Comment: So I'm wondering, which is the best way to manage a (10x10) matrix of 4 bits in hardware project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a way to solve this problem.

My understanding is that using 10x10 variables in VHDL introduces a lot of complexity because the compiler allocates all the resources they can need for them.

If you want to use a space to save your variables you can use something like a ram chip:

http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/models/simple_ram_model/

Then, you need to manage address cycles and reading/writing cycles, but the previous complexity seems to disappear.